# AngularJS - Is controller code executed line by line?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS, and is experimenting AngularJS with Twitch API.

I have a list of channels that I'm interested in, defined as `var channels`.

Then I use the `$http.get` function to loop through another array, `twitchList.channels`, which contains the API addresses that I'm supposed to call.

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('twitchList', []);

  app.controller('twitchController', ['$http', function($http){
    var twitchList = this;
    twitchList.channels = [];
    var channels = ["freecodecamp", "storbeck", "terakilobyte", "habathcx","RobotCaleb","thomasballinger","noobs2ninjas","beohoff", "MedryBW"];

    for (var i = 0; i < channels.length; i++ ) {
      twitchList.channels.push({
        name: channels[i],
        api: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + channels[i],
      })
    }  

    var data_list = []; 
    for (var j = 0; j < twitchList.channels.length; j++) {
      $http.get(twitchList.channels[j].api).success(function(data){
        data_list.push(data);
      }) 
    }

    // Issue arises here!
    console.log(data_list);
    console.log(data_list.length);

  }]);

})();
```

The API calls seems to be working perfectly, however, I need to get the results of the API call into an array, called `data_list`. Now, when I print `data_list`, and `data_list.length`, what happens is that `data_list.length` always returns 0, and `data_list` is sometimes populated (meaning it's either 0 size array or 9 size array). Even though the property of the array has a length 9, but calling `.length` always gives 0.

This let me think that the controller code is not executed line by line? Or is there something wrong with my logic?

Can someone give me a pointer? Thanks

Comment: $http is asynchronous and data_list will not be filed with your data from the server , hence its returns 0 , you can console it inside the success callback of $http

Comment: The code executes async data_list.push(data); will occur after the console.log.

Comment: @shushanthp Well, `data_list` is available on the scope but you're right that no data is pushed until the success callback has been invoked.

Comment: Thanks all, Is there anyway to keep blocking until all the deferred/promises are done?

Comment: Use `$q.all` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#methods_all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this line:

```
data_list.push(data);
```

will be executed when you receive a response on the http request sent a line above. Hence the following lines:

```
console.log(data_list);
console.log(data_list.length);
```

will output [] and 0

Comment: Thanks for your response! Is there a way to keep blocking until the async code is done?

Comment: Even if there is a such tool (I don't know actually whether it exists or not) it is a bad solution. JS uses non-blocking async calls based on callbacks

Comment: Hmm... I guess so, since JS is a single threaded application. I might need to re-think how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used it before, but could you possibly use `$q.all` in order to resolve multiple promises? I've used the equivalent `$.when` function in jQuery to achieve this in the past.

```
var data_list = []; 
var promise_array = [];
var request;

for (var j = 0; j < twitchList.channels.length; j++) {
   request = $http.get(twitchList.channels[j].api);
   request.success(function(data) {
      data_list.push(data);
   });
   promise_array.push(request);
}

$q.all(promise_array).then( function() {
   console.log(data_list);
   console.log(data_list.length);
});
```